# php function arguments in string to array

Tags: php, function, parsing, arguments

I have string

```
$argsInString = '"%s hello", \'%s world\', $foo->bar("anything", array(\'foo\' => 5 , \'bar\' => $a)),5, foo($s) ,$foo';
```

And I want convert to array like this:

```
$argsInArray = array('"%s hello"', '\'%s world\'', '$foo->bar("anything", array(\'foo\' => 5 , \'bar\' => $a))', '5', 'foo($s)', '$foo');
```

I try anything like this:

```
eval('$argsInArray = array(' . $argsInString . ');');
```

but this execute variables.

**Could you help me how create $argsInArray from $argsInString?**

EDIT:
If it succeed to write a regular expression that would clothed individual parameters, using a single quote ('), in the string, then the eval work as described above.

Or could you write regular expression preg_match_all('...', $argsInString, $argsInArray); this is best.

Comment: Basically any time you're using `eval` in your code, you're doing something wrong. Where does `$argsInString` come from and what exactly are you going to be using the output for?

Comment: Yes, you have right with eval, i try write regular expression, but i faild. With eval i try use php compiler, but this faild too. $argsInString come from framework if translate template, this is defined variable.

Comment: Doesn't the framework have some sort of built-in parsing method for these strings?

Comment: Framework has not method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Regex that will work on samples like this:

```
/(?: ?)([^,]*\(.*?\)|.+?)(?: ?)(?:,|$)/
```

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/hK6nN0

Update:
*to also match single and double quoted strings that contain `,` like:

`"%s, hello", \'%s, world\', 5`*

**`/(?: ?)([^,]*\(.*?\)|[^,]*'[^']*'|[^,]*"[^"]*"|.+?)(?: ?)(?:,|$)/`**

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/tD3cN9

Comment: Very very very nice, thank you. And I forgot one string $argsInString = '"%s, hello", \'%s, world\', $foo; like http://regex101.com/r/wF0xH8